# Foreign key in two columns and navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have one entity named "Team" and one named "Match"

In the "Match" entity I would like to have two properties, int HomeTeam, int AwayTeam which would contain the TeamId as a FK.

Is it possible to use a navagation property to fetch all matches(home and away games) for a specifik team with this setup?

If so, how is that done? 
I have only used navigation properties when the Id is in one column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes should look something like this:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

And your context like this:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().ToTable("Team");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>().ToTable("Match");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>().HasOptional(x => x.HomeTeam).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("HomeTeamId"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>().HasOptional(x => x.AwayTeam).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("AwayTeamId"));
    }
}
```

Basically you are using Fluent API to describe how your tables and relationships are configured.

**EDIT**

To answer your example query, get a list of all matches (both home and away) played by Team ID 1:

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

List<Match> matches = db.Matches.Where(
    t => t.HomeTeam.Id == 1 || t.AwayTeam.Id == 1
).ToList();
```

Comment: I figured that Fluent API would play an important role in this. Thanks alot! I will try it out tomorrow and accept.

Comment: One question, should I not add the HomeTeamId and AwayTeamId to the entity class as well? Or how would I add a new game between two TeamId's?

Comment: I prefer to keep things cleaner, since you can access the `Id`s through their respective container entities. I believe if you add a new game with the two teams correctly populated it will do everything for you (I love EF!) but be sure to test it first. If you have to add them after all, it's no big deal.

Comment: The OnModelCreating is causing errors with the Identity entities...
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Comment: When I remove OnModelCreating I am able to Add-Migration, but as soon as I add the code snippet I am not able to add a migration

Comment: I used the attributes [ForeignKey("AwayTeam")] [ForeignKey("HomeTeam")] instead, and are then able to migrate, is that the same thing as your modelcreating code?

Comment: `[ForeignKey]` is the annotation version of the same thing I did in Fluent API, yes. Personally I prefer to keep that stuff out of the models so that they are as POCO as possible, that's why I did it with Fluent API in the context configuration instead.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the list of matches from a navigation property in the Team entity? public virtual List<Match> Matches ?